# Linking MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple login page with MySQL but been having problem linking. I'm using xampp and eclipse as my php development tool. My database name is 'arc' with the table 'login'.

Script:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing that `mysql` extension is __removed__

Comment: can you please point which line I'm missing? @u_mulder

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php don't use `mysql_`

Answer (score 1):

According to php docs [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

You should check [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a way to go around it? or the new extension perhaps? I've read about using 'mysqli', but i'm not really familiar about it. I'm kinda new in this development.

Comment: @David The latest is the PDO stack which has many more options. But the thing you are trying to do is available in mysqli. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @David You literally replace `mysql` with `mysqli` in each function name - it can be done with a single search and replace. Although I'd recommend PDO over MySQLi myself because it makes it easier to switch away from MySQL if necessary.